# Getting means of one variable based on 2 other contigencies and running rcorr

Tags: r, correlation

I have data that looks like this:

**country_name**--------**City**-----------**area_change_pc** 
Bangladesh------------Bogra--------(33.33)  
Bangladesh------------Chandpur-- (-41.76)  
India---------------------Dewas-------(12.95)  
Pakistan----------------Quetta-------(4.08)  
Pakistan----------------Vehari--------(206.01)  
...

I then created a new variable called growth based on 4 contingencies: negative (<0), small (>=0, <15), medium (>=15, <50), and large (>= 50) with the code:

```
urbanization$growth[urbanization$area_change_pc<0]<-"1. negative"
urbanization$growth[urbanization$area_change_pc>=0 & area_change_pc<15]<-"2. small"
urbanization$growth[area_change_pc>=15 & area_change_pc<50]<-"3. medium"
urbanization$growth[area_change_pc>=50]<-"4. large"
```

Now the data looks like this:

**country_name**--------**City**-----------**area_change_pc**----**growth** 
Bangladesh------------Bogra--------(33.33)--------------------3. medium 
Bangladesh------------Chandpur-- (-41.76)-------------------1. negative
India---------------------Dewas-------(12.95)--------------------2. slow
Pakistan----------------Quetta-------(4.08)----------------------2. slow
Pakistan----------------Vehari--------(206.01)------------------4. large
...

I'm trying to create a table that would look like this:

```
             Bangladesh    India     Pakistan      Total
negative   
small 
medium
large
```

where each cell would be filled by the mean of `Area_Change` for those contingencies. For example, the first cell should be the mean `Area_Change` for all Bangladeshi cities with negative growth. I would like `Total` to be the average for only the growth group across all countries. I figured out how to get the mean `area_change_pc` by each country by using tapply:

```
with(urbanization, tapply(area_change_pc, list(growth,country_name), mean))
```

gives me (with the data values filled in - won't match the numbers I've given because I'm using the full data set, so I've left them out):

```
----------------Bangladesh    India     Pakistan
negative   
small 
medium
large
```

However, I can't figure out how to create a total column. Ultimately, I would like the total column so that I can test for significant differences between each country and growth group against the average for that growth group (so, is the average change in area for negative growth areas in Bangladesh significantly different from the average change in area across all countries?). Does anyone know how I might accomplish this?

Comment: I tried cleaning up the formatting somewhat; if I got some of the meaning wrong, please feel free to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make the example data reproducible:

```
urbanization <- read.table(text=
"country_name City area_change_pc
Bangladesh Bogra 33.33
Bangladesh Chandpur -41.76
India Dewas 12.95
Pakistan Quetta 4.08
Pakistan Vehari 206.01", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Second, here is an easier way to make the `growth` column

```
urbanization$growth <- cut(urbanization$area_change_pc,
                           breaks = c(-Inf, 0, 15, 50, Inf),
                           labels = c("1. negative", "2. slow", 
                                      "3. medium", "4. large"),
                           right = FALSE)
```

This data can be rearranged and aggregated using the `reshape2` package.

```
library("reshape2")

dcast(urbanization, growth~country_name, 
      fun.aggregate = mean, value.var="area_change_pc", 
      margins = "country_name")
```

which gives

```
       growth Bangladesh India Pakistan   (all)
1 1. negative     -41.76   NaN      NaN -41.760
2     2. slow        NaN 12.95     4.08   8.515
3   3. medium      33.33   NaN      NaN  33.330
4    4. large        NaN   NaN   206.01 206.010
```